# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite - removing encryption key

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to remove encryption key using this solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli
but the `PRAGMA rekey = NULL` does not work.
After executing this command I get:

> near "NULL": syntax error

The same error occurs when using sqlite browser application. When specifying not null password everything works correctly. The other thing is setting password to not-encrypted database. Using `PRAGMA key = 'password'` or `PRAGMA rekey = 'password'` simply does not work.

1. Is it possible to switch between encrypted and not-encrypted database? If yes then:
2. How to remove password in encrypted database?
3. How to set password in not-encrypted database?

I use SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher library for encryption.

EDIT: Related to: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/16684

Comment: A syntax error means you tried to execute an invalid query. Post your code. What does the *actual* statement look like? If you *don't* want to re-encrypt, you should just use `"PRAGMA rekey = NULL"`

Comment: That is exactly what I use. I can't believe there is an error in the statement. The same statement is generated by C# code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli. I use application "DB Browser for SQLCipher" for opening already encrypted database.

Comment: I have tested PRAGMA command in various sqlite interpreters. It seems the PRAGMA does not accept NULL value at all. Every time I have **near "NULL": syntax error**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am stuck on this too. Did you find a way around?

Comment: @Zeyad Unfortunately not. I just create new database.

Comment: @raV720 Thanks for replying back. Yeah me too I was never able to find a way around. I was actually trying to make a feature in my application where the user can decrypt the SQLite database in a button click but no luck :). SQLite keeps getting worse.